# try/except not catching a specific type of exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to catch a specific type of exception that is thrown inside a function call. I enclosed the function call inside a try/except block where the except block catches the specific exception being thrown. I still get a system fail stack trace for that exception, unless I also include a general catch for all exceptions. On including that block and checking the type of the exception being caught, I see that it is catching the type of exception I wanted to catch in the first block. No idea why this is happening.

Context: working on a google app engine app with webapp2 and ndb. The file functions has an **init**.py that imports all exceptions from exceptions.py

**Mock Code and Structure**

utils/functions/exceptions.py

```
"""
Custom exception types
"""

class InvalidParamsException(Exception):
def __init__(self, msg):
    self.msg = msg

def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.msg)
```

models/models.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
import utils.functions as func
<-->
class ModelClass(ndb.Model):

    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
         <-->
         raise func.InvalidParamsException("Invalid Params to function!")
         <-->
```

routes.py

```
import utils.functions as func
from models import ModelClass

class ModelClassHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            new_model = ModelClass.new()
        except func.InvalidParamsException as e:
            logging.debug("Caught the right Exception!!")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug(":(")
            logging.debug("EXCEPTION TYPE - %s"%str(type(e)))
```

The output that I get if I don't include that second general except block is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
  rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
  rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
  return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
  return handler.dispatch()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
  return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
  return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "{{my_path}}/routes.py", line 58, in post
  new_model = ModelClass.new()
File "{{my_path}}/models/models.py", line 559, in new
  raise func.InvalidParamsException("Invalid Params to function!")
InvalidParamsException: 'Invalid Params to function!'
```

If I do include that second block, I pass the route/function gracefully, and see this in the logs:

```
DEBUG    2016-03-25 01:01:03,221 routes.py:66] EXCEPTION TYPE - <class 'utils.functions.exceptions.InvalidParamsException'>
```

Help/Guidance much appreciated!!

Comment: `utils.functions.InvalidParamsException` and `utils.functions.exceptions.InvalidParamsException` would be two different exceptions. The one you catch with the `except Exception` looks right; your attempt to raise `func.InvalidParamsException` when `func` is `utils.functions` (not `utils.functions.exceptions`) does not.

Comment: It would appear though that python can track the import path; the place where the exception is raised references the exception in the same way that the try/except block does, through the functions module, which has imported it. Do you know any reason why it would track the two differently?

Comment: further, I changed the first block to catch func.exceptions.InvalidParamsExceptions and still saw the issue.

Comment: You should set your paths in appengine_config.py and then it is set correctly before any of your code is imported.  The consider placing your exception definition in a place that all code can import consistently.

Comment: My point is that I don't see how `models/models.py` can raise `func.InvalidParamsException` when that exception is defined in `func.exceptions`, not `func`.

Comment: @chepner if you look at "context" above you'll see an explanation; the __init__.py file for the functions module/file imports all the exceptions, so they can be accessed through a pointer to functions.

Comment: @TimHoffman That sounds really valuable, but I don't know what you're referring to. I haven't seen anything on setting paths in appengine_config. Can you point me towards reference documentation? I thought that this location was one which could be referenced consistently; I haven't seen a problem with it until now.

Comment: Just put your sys.path manipulation or any other python code you want run before any instance starts.  ie setting environment variables etc,... You should not have any path manipulation in any module.  Keep it outside of your code base.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that Python raises exceptions as imported in the current namespace. My best evicende for that is the fact that the last line of the traceback calls the raised exception "InvalidParamsException" and not "somemodule.InvalidParamsException".

Thereby, I would suggest resolving the namespace conflicts importing explicitly the exception into the namespace of "routes.py":

`from utils.functions.exceptions import InvalidParamsException`

and catching the exception by its now-resolved namespace name:

`except InvalidParamsException as inv_param_exp:
    <...>`